# MongoDB schema to manage different price amount for different dates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-design

I need to save and manage different price amount for different dates and date ranges, for particular product. So there will be numbers of products all having different prices for different dates and date ranges.

I am thinking to create a separate MongoDb collection, Which will have reference to product collection, amount and date. Also for date range (i.e - from 9 Aug. to 11 Aug.) I will generate individual documents.

I need to find specific prices on specific date using Node.Js and MongoDB queries. Am I thinking right way?
Thank You.

One more question- Let us say, I have one document containing ISO Date Ex. ISODate("2019-08-10T00:00:00.000+0000") and that days price, What will be MongoDB query to get data of specific date Ex. 10th Aug. ?

Comment: I do not recommend to create a new collection to maintain prices on different dates. In that we need to give ProdcutId as a reference. Though, we have functions like $lookup MongoDB there is no guarantee that is supported by ORM. The best to do this in MonogDB is to store that data as JSON array in the same collections. ie You can take another prices as JSON array and put it in the same product document.

Comment: @AmaranadhMeda Thank you for suggestion, But I need to store different prices for next six months, Is it possible to save that mush of data in array of objects, I also need to fetch data with different conditions, I already have lots of things in my product document.

Comment: Then create a new collection and add index on ProductId field of new collection.

Comment: One more question- Let us say, I have one document containing ISO Date Ex. ISODate("2019-08-10T00:00:00.000+0000") and that days price, What will be MongoDB query to get data of specific date Ex. 10th Aug. ?

Comment: db.product.find({productDate: new Date("<YYYY-mm-dd>")}) this must work for normal scenarios.